# Create Giant Cloud forms in EVEE (Hurricane from space)

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, displacement

I would like to create giant clouds, like a Hurican on Jupiter in EVEE (don't have the computer for cycle, it's a 560 frames animation !)
I  approach this with a displace modifier but I can't get this look (deformation follow lines like the wind).
I created the scene so I have the geometry I want but not material and displace. I don't think I should create a volume material, or use the clouds modifier from 2.9. Below pics of the scene and the render i would like to achieve :
[image: Scene in Blender]
[image: Jupiter Clouds]